# Reconnect ConEmu to "orphaned" processes

Tags: windows, command-line, robocopy, conemu

ConEmu crashed on me whilst hosting a very long running robocopy command (it has already run for several days). Robocopy is still running in the background, I can see it listed in Task Manager and I don't want to kill it if possible. I want to be able to see robocopy's output.

ConEmu can attach to applications but when I try this it does not show any of the previously hosted processes, i.e. robocopy

Is there a way of reattaching to the robocopy process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided the "crash" message, so who can guess???

Most probably, your `conhost.exe` was crashed. Check this in TaskManager. If so, there is no more "console" and ConEmu can't attach anything.

#### Update

If the [RealConsole](https://conemu.github.io/en/RealConsole.html) is alive, you may try to [ShowWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548.aspx) on it. The window has `ConsoleWindowClass` window class name. I believe it's possible via PowerShell script, but I'm not sure how exactly.

Also, you may try to attach the RealConsole to ConEmu. The method may fail, if OS forbid ConEmu to attach the console.

1. Run `ConEmu.exe -detached`
2. Run (from <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) `ConEmuC64.exe /ADMIN /ATTACH /CONPID=your-pid`. Where `your-pid` is the process identifier of the running process. Is it `cmd.exe` or `robocopy.exe`?

Comment: `conhost.exe` is still running

Comment: Maximus, just saw you are the author of ConEmu, thanks for making a great program. I use it daily.

Comment: What about processes `ConEmu*.exe`?

Comment: ConEmu*.exe ended after an exception when I resized the ConEmu window. I know i should have copied the exception message but I was concerned about ending robocopy. I just want to know if there is any way of getting back to see the output.

Comment: When GUI process (ConEmu.exe) is ended unexpectedly, Server process (ConEmuC.exe) shows the RealConsole automatically. So, you have not provided some critical information.

Comment: Well, two options were described.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated to 160301 (had to manually uninstall 1401016)

Comment: Thanks Maximus, Neither option worked for me, sorry. I guess in this instance, on my machine, it does not work. I will accept the answer even though I cannot verify if this is the correct solution. 

I will continue to use your great program.